# End kernel panic problem

Tags: kernel

I'm a newbie, trying to connect a gps to my raspberry pi 3 bit. After rebooting I can't get any further, and receive the message

```
End Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount roof fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

I'm trying to use the rescue system but every time I using a `sudo` command It says `sudo: not found`.

Comment: Repair or reflash the SD card. Your `sudo` command sits on the root fs which you are unable to mount.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [raspbian: unable to mount root fs on uknown block](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89460/raspbian-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-uknown-block)

Answer (score 1):

Your SD card is faulty, or at least the data that's on it is flawed/has issues.

1. Try burning your OS image (Raspbian) on the SD card
2. If that doesn't work, try another SD card.